# Convert .txt file (ANSI codification) to .Arff without losing accents

Tags: java, netbeans, weka, arff

I've got serious trouble to find how to convert an .txt file in ANSI codification to .arff file in weka without loosing some accents and the meaning of a word in the process. I'm reading articles in SPANISH and the problem is that the words that have accents are bad converted because the letter with the accent is converted like this.

### My original .txt   |   .arff file result of the conversion

Minería            |  Miner�a

The letter "í" is lost in the process.

My code now is this (code provided by weka university)

```
public Instances createDataset(String directoryPath) throws Exception {

FastVector atts = new FastVector(2);
atts.addElement(new Attribute("filename", (FastVector) null));
atts.addElement(new Attribute("contents", (FastVector) null));
Instances data = new Instances("text_files_in_" + directoryPath, atts, 0);

File dir = new File(directoryPath);
String[] files = dir.list();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  if (files[i].endsWith(".txt")) {
try {
  double[] newInst = new double[2];
  newInst[0] = (double)data.attribute(0).addStringValue(files[i]);
  File txt = new File(directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
  // meto codigo nuevo aqui dentro


  // hasata aqui
  InputStreamReader is;
  is = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(txt));
  StringBuffer txtStr = new StringBuffer();
  int c;
  while ((c = is.read()) != -1) {
    txtStr.append((char)c);
    // s pstir de aqui contamino yo el codigo
     // System.out.println("Sale " + is.toString();

  }
  newInst[1] = (double)data.attribute(1).addStringValue(txtStr.toString());
  data.add(new Instance(1.0, newInst));
} catch (Exception e) {
  //System.err.println("failed to convert file: " + directoryPath + File.separator + files[i]);
}
  }
}
return data;
```

}

I'm using Netbeans to cast files from a file in my computer. 
You may think that I'm asking the same thing from other posts in this page but really I'm not because what I really need is a converter that converts correctly the accents in Spanish.

I've tried to change the codification in Netbeans to UTF-8 and to ANSI, but none of the solutions worked for me ( I went to the configuration file in Netbeans8.1 --> etc --> netbeans.conf  and add there -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 in the line netbeans_default_options=.......... but still doesn't work). I'm getting a bit frustrated with this problem.

Well I found a partial  solution after loosing my mind. In fact this solution isn't a real solution so I hoe that one day someone answers something that may save the world of datamining. The solution consist in saving the text in UTF-8 without BOM (UTF-8 sin BOM). You have also to configure Netbeans to read UTF8 as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, my solution was encode to ANSI.

I used Notepad ++

Steps:

- Open your file
- Go to the top panel
- Enconding -> Encode in ANSI